# Pasting Cells from Excel into Datagridview VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

I have this code that i use to paste into my datagridview under the KeyDown event:

```
 If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
        Try
            For Each line As String In Clipboard.GetText.Split(vbNewLine)
                If Not line.Trim.ToString = "" Then
                    Dim item() As String = line.Trim.Split(vbTab)
                    Me.Datagridview1.Rows.Add(item)
                End If
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, My.Application.Info.Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End If
```

It works fine to paste data, the problem is when i paste blank cells in to the datagridview it ignores some of the blanks and shift the cells with content.

```
Example when i paste this:

            Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
       Row1    a       b              d
       Row2            f       g

This is what i get:

            Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
       Row1    a       b               d
       Row2    f       g
```

Does anyone know what could i be doing wrong or how to improve my code?

Comment: You are going to have problems with the “Copy” aspect of this. My tests show that if the cell is empty in Excel, the copy command (Ctrl-C) will “IGNORE” those cells. This creates a problem if for example there is only ONE (1) item in a row and all the other cells are empty. You will not be able to tell “which” column the cell belongs in.

Comment: Therefore, I do not think you will be able to do this with a simple “Ctrl-C-V” (copy-paste) without doing something in Excel to make the “empty” cells not empty… at least from the copy-paste perspective. You may consider using “Interop” or some other  third party Excel library to accomplish this.

Comment: Let me clarify my first comment. It should read… For each Excel ROW when you “copy” (Ctrl-C) a selection in Excel, it will IGNORE all the empty cells BEFORE the first non-empty cell with data AND it will also IGNORE all empty cells AFTER the last non-empty cell with data in that row. If there is an empty cell between the first cell with data and the last cell with data… it WILL get those empty cells. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is exactly the issuse im having with the empty cells.

Comment: Found a solution using @Pavlinll solution Dim item() As String = line.Split(vbTab(0)), in my code i was using line.TRIM.Split, i removed the TRIM and problem solved thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
Dim item() As String = line.Trim.Split(vbTab(0))
```

to this

```
Dim item() As String = line.Split(vbTab(0))
```

or this, if you want to trim content of individual cells, but that's not good idea

```
Dim item() As String = line.Split(vbTab(0)).Select(Function(X) X.Trim).ToArray
```

That .Trim call is stripping the initial TAB from your line and shifts your data.

Comment: Dim item() As String = line.Split(vbTab(0))